# Why geom_abline does not honor scales_x_reverse?

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I have been struggling with `geom_abline` commands when combined with `scale_x_reverse`.

For instance, the following code creates a plot of 10 points following the identity. I can reverse the x axis with `scale_x_reverse`, but when I add an identity using `geom_abline` the red identity line is not reversed.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(1,10))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_abline(color="red") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits=c(10,-10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10,10)) + 
  ggtitle("I would expect the red line to be on top of the points")
```

It seems that `geom_abline` plots a line of `intercept=0, slope=1`, but does not honor the scale transformation.

As a workaround I know that I can force the slope to do what I want:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(1,10))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=-1, color="red") +
  scale_x_reverse(limits=c(10,-10)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-10,10)) + 
  ggtitle("I would expect the red line to be on top of the points")
```

I find this `geom_abline` behaviour confusing and I don't understand the reasons why this was implemented this way. Given the good design of ggplot, I am sure that there must be a good logical reason, but I have been unable to understand it.

Can anyone please explain it to me?

Comment: It seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/46) that `geom_abline` does not work with scales.

Comment: Although in this case it seems that the problem is actually different. `geom_abline` uses `geom_segment` internally and `geom_segment` has the same problem (add `geom_segment(x = -11, xend=11, y=-11, yend=11, color='blue')` instead of `geom_abline`).

Comment: Interestingly, this seems to be only an issue when using fixed `x`, `y`, but not when using it inside an `aes` call. Seems related to [this issue](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there answer is that this is just a bug. It is related to a [problem](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/706) in `geom_segment`. It works when the aestetics are specified inside `aes`, but not otherwise.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(1,10),y=seq(1,10))) + 
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  scale_x_reverse() + 
  geom_segment(x = -10, xend=10, y=-10, yend=10, color='blue') +
  geom_segment(data = data.frame(x = -10, xend=10, y=-10, yend=10), 
               aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend),
               color='red')
```

[image: problem with geom_segment]

However, there seems to be a more general problem with using `geom_abline`, `geom_hline`, `geom_vline` together with scales. See [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/46) for more information.